# How do you intercept/reroute phone call but have destination number appear correct?

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver, google-voice

Trying to replicate what Google Voice on Android does. Specifically you dial a number in the dialer, in this case 123-456-7890. Google Voice intercepts the call in a BroadcastReceiver, and reroutes it to a "shadow number (in this case 1-916-538-1453). However it manages to keep "1234567890" as the destination number and displays custom text in the blue box that comes down and then disappears. Does anyone know how you would do this?

[image]

Comment: From looking into the telephony stuff previously, I have found a lot of it to be protected by signature level permissions.  Thus you cannot access a lot of the functions and/or features unless you're app is signed with the same signing key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After doing more research on this topic and asking people that have worked on this in the past, I have determined that this is basically impossible. As Chris mentioned in the comment, it comes down to having your app be signed with the Google key in order for it to work. The best workaround is to display a toast (possibly custom toast) showing the custom text and the original number and then rewrite the call log to display the correct number.